# MySQL question, How to loop through a list and return number of occurances for each in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a list of values.

'abc123', 'bdg432', 'eds321', 'hgd765', 'fds987', 'tdq343'

These values exist many times in a field in the "Items" table called "Itmcode".

I would like to execute the following query for each of the items codes from the list above.

```
SELECT
    Items.Itmcode, 
    COUNT(*) AS `Total Items Sold`
FROM
    Items
WHERE
    Items.Itmcode =  {Item Code From List} AND
    Items.ItmStatus > 2
```

getting a result as follows.

| Itmcode | Total Items Sold |
| --- | --- |
| abc123 | 4248 |
| bdg432 | 98 |
| eds321 | 78427 |
| hgd765 | 151 |
| tdq343 | 72164 |

I am pretty sure I need to use a loop to do this but i am not sure how.

I have never tried using loops before. I have looked at a commonly referenced example of a stored procedure that creates a list of numbers and outputs them into a string. For whatever reason I cant transfer that concept to reality. I am hoping that someone here can give help me to understand what I think is probably the simplest answer in the universe. I am just not getting it.

Comment: Do you need to report 0 if there are none sold for one of the things in your list?  (Ideally not, your client knows which items codes it was looking for and can deduce 0 from a row not being returned for an item code)

Comment: Either way, you don't want a loop, just an IN operation and a GROUP BY, plus a join if you need 0 counts returned

Comment: Your table seems wrong though; an Items table should only have one row per item; sales would go in a separate table

Comment: I do not need to report the zero.

Comment: This is not the actual table structure. I am just trying to simplify it. I meant to indicate that this is a line item table.

Comment: In the actual query, there are going to be over 800 such codes in the list. that is why I was thinking running a loop

Comment: looping is almost never something you want to do in sql.  with a long list, you should avoid IN on the line item table, though, since that is sometimes not optimized well.  just join from your actual item table instead, so something like `select items.itmcode, count(*) total_sales from items join sales on sales.itmcode=items.itmcode where items.itmcode in (?,?,?...) group by items.itmcode`

Comment: Is there no real way to iterate through a list and run the exact sql command i have above for each in item in the list and return it as the same result set?

Comment: You can do that in the client, sure.  It's just going to be significantly slower

Comment: without procedure and using cursor inside procedure I don't see any alternatives to achieve it. but you can do it at client side as @ysth mentioned.

Comment: And there's no _reason_ to.  You have a list of items, you make a single request and get one (at most) row per item in the result.  Looping is antithetical to how you should be thinking about SQL

Comment: I used the suggest GROUP BY method and ended up using 2 left joins to get it done in the end but it works great. Thanks for the help.